# Restrict the folders that lies in scope of service workers

Tags: javascript, scope, web-worker, service-worker

How to restrict the folders that lie under the scope while registering service workers.

I have a folder structure like this.

```
-root
 -folder1
   -subfolder1
   -subfolder2
   -subfolder3
   -file.js
   -file2.js
   -css1.css
   -css2.css
   -serviceworker.js
```

According to my understanding:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
       .register('serviceworker.js',)
        .then(function(reg) {

            console.log('Registration succeeded', reg);

       })
```

Here the serviceworker.js file is under the folder1 folder, which means that all the files and sub folders inside folder1 are under the scope.

What I want:
Is there any way to restrict the files and folders that come under the scope of service workers say subfolder1 and file.js.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just create a `serviceworker` folder and put the service worker and anything you want to restrict it to there?

Answer (score 3):

You can't specifically restrict a service worker's scope to only apply to one sub-path but not another when they both share the same parent path.

The most straightforward approach would be to explicitly check the URL in your `fetch` handler and only call `event.respondWith()` when the URL matches one of the paths/files you care about. If you don't call `event.respondWith()`, the `fetch` handler will basically be a no-op, and the service worker won't be involved in responding to the request.

E.g.:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  if (event.request.url.includes('subfolder1')) {
    event.respondWith(/* your caching/network logic */);
  }
  // By not calling event.respondWith() for certain requests,
  // the service worker will effectively be a no-op.
});
```

Comment: Does anybody knows whether Workbox provides this function?